# unfortunately APP HAS STOPPED : inserting into db with php from my android pp

Tags: java, php, android

The purpose of this app is to fill in a form and insert its informations into 
a database with PHP. The problem is when I press the button an error comes out but I already tested it and am sure that the PHP code is right.

Errors:

```
  AndroidRuntime(1334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  AndroidRuntime(1334): Process: com.star.storesriders, PID: 1334            
  AndroidRuntime(1334):Reclamation$1.onClick(Reclamation.java:41)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  AndroidRuntime(1334): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  AndroidRuntime(1334):atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  AndroidRuntime(1334): atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 AndroidRuntime(1334):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 AndroidRuntime(1334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Layout XML file:

```
    <RelativeLayout           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.storesriders.Connexion" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numcl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/objet"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/objet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/store"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/objet"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
    android:text="NumClient"
    android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/reclamer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/description"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/numcl"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:text="Objet"
    android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/objet"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:text="Intitulé Store"
    android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/store"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:text="Nom Client"
    android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nomcl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/store"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reclamer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    android:background="#fb9b45"
    android:text="Valider"
    android:textColor="#1e5829"
    android:width="140dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reclamer"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:shadowColor="#c4099f"
    android:text="Reclamation"
    android:textColor="#d1192e"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Java code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Reclamation extends Activity {
Button rec;
EditText nomcl,objet,description,store,numcl;
connexionservice connexionservice;
public void onCreate (Bundle SavedInstanceState ){
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reclamation);
    rec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reclamer); 
    rec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View V){
            nomcl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nomcl);
            objet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.objet);
            description = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
            store = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.store);
            numcl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numcl);
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            if (!(nomcl).getText().toString().equals("") && !(objet).getText().toString().equals("")&& !(description).getText().toString().equals("")&&!(store).getText().toString().equals("")&&!(numcl).getText().toString().equals("")){
                connexionservice.execute((nomcl).getText().toString().trim(),(objet).getText().toString().trim(),(description).getText().toString().trim(),(store).getText().toString().trim(),(numcl).getText().toString().trim());
                findViewById(R.id.reclamer).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
public boolean testconnexionInternet (){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null){
        State networkState= networkInfo.getState();
        if (networkState.compareTo(State.CONNECTED)==0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class connexionservice extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0){
        if(testconnexionInternet()){
            try{
                URL url = new URL ("http://myIP:8880/StoresRiders/service.php?action=reclamer&nomcl="+arg0[0]+"&objet="+arg0[1]+"&description="+arg0[2]+"&store="+arg0[3]+"&numcl="+arg0[4]);
                URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
                return in.readLine();

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("exception",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    if (!isCancelled()){
        if(result.equals("succes")){
            startActivity(new Intent(Reclamation.this,Menu_agent.class));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Merci de remplir tous les champs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        findViewById(R.id.reclamer).setEnabled(true);
    }
}
}

public void onDestroy (){
    super.onDestroy();
    connexionservice.cancel(true);
}
}
```

Please help. After pressing the button "Unfortunately SR has stopped".

Answer (score 2):

Sooo, there might be a few issues here..

1. connexionservice was never being instantiated..

   ```
   connexionservice = new connexionservice();
   ```
2. connexionservice.execute was never being called..
3. You were missing a  end tag in your XML file...

Here is some code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.example.storesriders.Connexion">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numcl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/objet"
            android:ems="10"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/objet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:ems="10">

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/objet"
            android:ems="10"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
            android:text="NumClient"
            android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/reclamer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/description"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/numcl"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
            android:text="Objet"
            android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/objet"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:text="Intitulé Store"
            android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/store"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:text="Nom Client"
            android:textColor="#1a0d4f"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nomcl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/store"
            android:ems="10"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/reclamer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
            android:background="#fb9b45"
            android:text="Valider"
            android:textColor="#1e5829"
            android:width="140dp"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reclamer"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:shadowColor="#c4099f"
            android:text="Reclamation"
            android:textColor="#d1192e"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Reclamation extends Activity {
    Button rec;
    EditText nomcl, objet, description, store, numcl;
    connexionservice connexionservice;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reclamation);
        rec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reclamer);
        rec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nomcl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomcl);
                objet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.objet);
                description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
                store = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.store);
                numcl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numcl);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                if (!anyEmpty(nomcl, objet, description, store, numcl)) {
                    executeConnectionService(
                        trimAndGetText(nomcl),
                        trimAndGetText(objet),
                        trimAndGetText(description),
                        trimAndGetText(store),
                        trimAndGetText(numcl)
                    );
                    rec.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String trimAndGetText(TextView textView) {
        String s = String.valueOf(textView.getText());
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return s.trim();
    }

    private void executeConnectionService(String nomcl, String objet, String description, String store, String numcl) {
        if (connexionservice == null ||
            connexionservice.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            connexionservice = new connexionservice();
            connexionservice.execute(nomcl, objet, description, store, numcl);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "connexionservice still runnningngn.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private boolean anyEmpty(TextView... textViews) {
        for (TextView tv : textViews) {
            if ("".equals(String.valueOf(tv.getText()))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
    public boolean testconnexionInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            State networkState = networkInfo.getState();
            if (networkState.compareTo(State.CONNECTED) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class connexionservice extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            if (testconnexionInternet()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://myIP:8880/StoresRiders/service.php?action=reclamer&nomcl=" + arg0[0] + "&objet=" + arg0[1] + "&description=" + arg0[2] + "&store=" + arg0[3] + "&numcl=" + arg0[4]);
                    URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
                    return in.readLine();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("exception", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                if (result.equals("succes")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Reclamation.this, Menu_agent.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Merci de remplir tous les champs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                findViewById(R.id.reclamer).setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        connexionservice.cancel(true);
    }
}
```